# How could i get the current vim mode in Visual Studio Code with vim plugin

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscodevim

as the title.
i am developing the plugin with vscode/vim plugin,but i got the problem about get the current vim mode(eg:normal),i try to get it with cursor style,is there any ohter solution?Such as with an api
i try to get it with cursor style